# Cannot make plotly config work in R

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I want to display a plotly plot using R-shiny, but with no mode bar. I am trying to use the config option but it is not working. Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(

      plotlyOutput("plot")

)
server <- function(input, output, session) {



  output$plot <- renderPlotly({

    p <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
    config(p, displayModeBar = FALSE)

    p
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This code displays the plot correctly but ignores the configuration. The mode bar still appears. I also tried different configuration options, like displaylogo = FALSE, collaborate = FALSE to hide the logo and collaboration option, respectively, and they are ignored as well.

Does anybody have any idea of why it's not working? my plotly version is 4.8.0

I would really appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: Just assign `p<- config(p, displayModeBar = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is defining your p as:

```
  p <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length) %>%
       config(p, displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

or just running:

```
plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length) %>%
config(p, displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

Comment: use plotly::config() if you get a class request as result (see https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/746)